# Constructing lists in an efficient way

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a list of functions and I want to separate them into two lists:

1. a list that contains the functions that have at least one zero and
2. a list that contains the functions that do not have zeros.

Let's say that the list of functions is this:

```
listoffuns = 
 Flatten[Table[
   Rationalize[a + b*Cos[c*(t + d)], 0], {a, 0.0003, 0.009, 0.0001}, {b, 0.01, 0.1, 
    0.01}, {c, 1, 4, 1}, {d, 2, 5, 1}]]
```

I initially used this:

```
lengthoflistoffuns = Length[listoffuns]; list1 = {}; list2 = {}; table = 
 For[i = 1, i <= lengthoflistoffuns, i = i + 1, 
  If[Resolve[Exists[t, listoffuns[[i]] == 0], Reals], AppendTo[list1, listoffuns[[i]]], 
   AppendTo[list2, listoffuns[[i]]]]]
```

because, back then, the number of functions was small and I didn't have problems concerning efficiency. But now it is a problem for me. I know that For and `AppendTo` are inefficient commands in *Mathematica* and I want to replace them. I thought that it would be an efficient way for constructing the above mentioned lists if I used `Sow` and `Reap` instead of `AppendTo` and defined a pure function that would do the separation applied with the Map command to the values of i in the For loop. So help me do this in the way that I proposed or in your own (efficient) way. This is what I tried:

```
sepfun := If[Resolve[Exists[t, listoffuns[[#]] == 0], Reals], 
   list1 = Reap[Sow[listoffuns[[#]]]], list2 = Reap[Sow[listoffuns[[#]]]]] &

table1 = Table[j, {j, 1, lengthoflistoffuns, 1}]

sepfun /@ table1
```

I didn't construct a representative problem before because I expected answers that would also fit my real problem. So, I 'll cite now my real problem.

I want to construct `list1`, `list2`, `list3` and `list4` in an efficient way. So, I want to modify `table8` and `table9` in my code. The `listoffuns` corresponds, in my real problem, to the `listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr`. Each of these functions correspond to an ordered 4-tuple (α, β, Ω, γ). In `table8` I want to gather the 4-tuples (α, β, Ω, γ) that correspond to functions that have at least one zero in `list1` and in `list2` the rest of them. In `table9` I want to gather the 4-tuples (α, β, Ω, γ) that correspond to functions that have only simple zeros in `list4` and in `list3` the rest of them (functions that have at least one zero with multiplicity two or greater). In `table9` the functions that I separate are the functions that belong to the list `listofMelnfunwhichhavezeros`.

I have fixed γ in my code so some commands seem to be unnecessary but they 're not because I want to be able to vary γ if needed on my way to the solution of the whole problem.

Here is a link that might be helpful for some people  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_%28mathematics%29.

Although, I asked this question to solve the above mentioned problem any adaptations  that can easily be done in my code that drastically save time are welcome. I know that there are because this is my first program in mathematica and now that I have learned it a little if I did it from the beginning I would have made some changes but I don't know if they are worth the time concerning the gained performance.

I don't know if it's useful for anyone but I tried to separate the functions `listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr` using the suggestions of *Histograms* and *LLlAMnYP* and it took 786 s (13.1 min).

```
c0 = 0.001; initvlofγ = 1; finvlofγ = 1; incrstepofγ = 1;

s = Partition[
 Flatten[Table[
  NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x2[t], x2'[t] == -γ*Sin[x1[t]], 
   x1[0] == -Pi + c0, 
    x2[0] == 0.9*(Sqrt[γ]*(-Pi + c0) + Sqrt[γ]*Pi), 
     WhenEvent[
      Abs[x2[t]] <= 10^-2, {"StopIntegration", end = t}]}, {x1, 
       x2}, {t, 0, Infinity}, MaxSteps -> 10^6], {γ, initvlofγ, 
        finvlofγ, incrstepofγ}]], 2];

lengthofs = Length[s]; listofx1 = Table[s[[x1, 1, 2]], {x1, 1,  
 lengthofs, 1}];

listofx2 = Table[s[[x2, 2, 2]], {x2, 1, lengthofs, 1}];

listofendfordifferentvlsofγ = Table[s[[nvofγ, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]], {nvofγ, 1,  
 lengthofs, 1}];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[
  ConditionalExpression[{listofx1[[nvofγ]][t], listofx2[[nvofγ]][t]},
   0 <= t <= listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]], {nvofγ, 1, 
    lengthofs, 1}]], {t, 0, Max[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-Pi - 1, Pi + 1}, All}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\)]\)", 
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)"}]

initvlofα = 0.1; finvlofα = 2; incrstepofα = 0.1; 
initvlofβ = 0.1; finvlofβ = 2; incrstepofβ = 0.1;
initvlofΩ = 0.1; finvlofΩ = 2; incrstepofΩ = 0.1;

listofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ = 
 Flatten[Table[
  With[{α = α, β = β, Ω = Ω}, (α*Cos[Ω*(#2 + t0)]*#1 - β*#1^2) &], {α,     
   initvlofα, 
    finvlofα, incrstepofα}, {β, initvlofβ, finvlofβ, incrstepofβ}, {Ω,
     initvlofΩ, finvlofΩ, incrstepofΩ}]];

timestep = 1;

x2tdyadsfordifferentvlsofγ = 
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[{listofx2[[nvofγ]][ζ], ζ}, {nvofγ, 1, lengthofs, 
   1}, {ζ, 0, listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]], timestep}]], 2];

listoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads = 
 Table[1 + 
  Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep], {nvofγ, 1, 
   lengthofs, 1}];

lengthoflistoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads = 
 Length[listoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads];

table1 = Table[
 Sum[listoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads[[index1]], {index1, 
  index1}], {index1, 1, lengthoflistoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads, 1}];

table2 = Drop[Riffle[table1, table1], -1];

table3 = Riffle[Table[0^nvofγ, {nvofγ, 1, lengthofs, 1}], 1];

pairs = Partition[Prepend[table2 + table3, 1], 2];

x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ = 
 Take[x2tdyadsfordifferentvlsofγ, #] & /@ pairs;

lengthoflistofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ =   
 Length[listofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ];

listofoneplusfloorvls = listoflengthsofsublistsofx2tdyads;

listofpositionsofoneplusfloorvlswhichareeven = 
 Flatten[Position[listofoneplusfloorvls, _?EvenQ]];

listofx2tdyadstobeinserted = 
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[{listofx2[[
   nvofγ]][(Sum[
    timestep, {index3, 
     Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep]}] + 
      Sum[timestep, {index3, 
       Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep] - 
        1}])/2], (Sum[
         timestep, {index3, 
          Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep]}] + 
           Sum[timestep, {index3, 
            Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep] - 1}])/
             2}, {nvofγ,   
              listofpositionsofoneplusfloorvlswhichareeven}]],2];

lengthoflistofx2tdyadstobeinserted = Length[listofx2tdyadstobeinserted];

x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγbeforemodification
 = Table[AppendTo[
  x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ[[
   listofpositionsofoneplusfloorvlswhichareeven[[pos]]]], 
    listofx2tdyadstobeinserted[[pos]]], {pos, 
     lengthoflistofx2tdyadstobeinserted}];

listoflengthsofx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγbef
 oremodification = 
  Table[Length[
   x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγbeforemodificat
    ion[[pos]]], {pos, lengthoflistofx2tdyadstobeinserted}];

x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγ = 
 Table[Permute[ 
  x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγbeforemodificat
   ion[[pos]], 
    Cycles[{{    
   listoflengthsofx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγbef
    oremodification[[pos]] - 1, 
     listoflengthsofx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvls
      ofγbeforemodification[[pos]]}}]], {pos, 
       lengthoflistofx2tdyadstobeinserted}];

finalx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ = 
 ReplacePart[
  x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ, 
   Table[listofpositionsofoneplusfloorvlswhichareeven[[pos]] -> 
    x2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtoevenvlsofγ[[pos]], {pos,
     lengthoflistofx2tdyadstobeinserted}]];

listoflengthsofsublistsoffinalx2tdyads = 
 Table[Length[
  finalx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ[[
   index]]], {index, lengthofs}];

listoffwedgegvlsfordifferentvlsofαβΩvaryingγ = 
 Table[Apply[listofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ[[index2]], 
  finalx2tdyadsorganizedinsublistscorrespondingtodifferentvlsofγ[[
   nvofγ]], {1}], {index2, 1, lengthoflistofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ, 
    1}, {nvofγ, 1, lengthofs, 1}];

listofthefirstfactorsofSimpsrule = 
 Table[((Sum[
  timestep, {index3, 
   Floor[listofendfordifferentvlsofγ[[nvofγ]]/timestep]}] - 
    0)/(listoflengthsofsublistsoffinalx2tdyads[[nvofγ]] - 1))/
     3, {nvofγ, 1, lengthofs, 1}];

numberofvlsofα = Abs[finvlofα - initvlofα]/incrstepofα + 1;
numberofvlsofβ = Abs[finvlofβ - initvlofβ]/incrstepofβ + 1;
numberofvlsofΩ = Abs[finvlofΩ - initvlofΩ]/incrstepofΩ + 1;

listofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Flatten[Table[
  listoffwedgegvlsfordifferentvlsofαβΩvaryingγ[[index4, index5, 
   1]], {index4, 1, numberofvlsofα*numberofvlsofβ*numberofvlsofΩ, 
    1}, {index5, 1, lengthofs, 1}]];

lengthoflistofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Length[listofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule];

listofthesecondtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Flatten[Table[
  4*Sum[listoffwedgegvlsfordifferentvlsofαβΩvaryingγ[[index4, index5,
   index6]], {index6, 2, 
    listoflengthsofsublistsoffinalx2tdyads[[index5]] - 1, 
     2}], {index4, 1, numberofvlsofα*numberofvlsofβ*numberofvlsofΩ, 
      1}, {index5, 1, lengthofs, 1}]];

lengthoflistofthesecondtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Length[listofthesecondtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule];

listofthethirdtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Flatten[Table[
  2*Sum[listoffwedgegvlsfordifferentvlsofαβΩvaryingγ[[index4, index5,
   index7]], {index7, 
    3, (listoflengthsofsublistsoffinalx2tdyads[[index5]] - 1) - 1, 
     2}], {index4, 1, numberofvlsofα*numberofvlsofβ*numberofvlsofΩ, 
      1}, {index5, 1, lengthofs, 1}]];

lengthoflistofthethirdtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Length[listofthethirdtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule];

listofthefourthtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Flatten[Table[
  listoffwedgegvlsfordifferentvlsofαβΩvaryingγ[[index4, 
   index5, (listoflengthsofsublistsoffinalx2tdyads[[index5]] - 1) + 
    1]], {index4, 1, numberofvlsofα*numberofvlsofβ*numberofvlsofΩ, 
     1}, {index5, 1, lengthofs, 1}]];

lengthoflistofthefourthtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule = 
 Length[listofthefourthtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule];

listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegrbeforemultiplyingwiththefirstfactors = 
 Table[Rationalize[
  listofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule[[index8]] + 
   listofthesecondtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule[[index8]] + 
    listofthethirdtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule[[index8]] + 
     listofthefourthtermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule[[index8]], 
      0], {index8, 1, 
       lengthoflistofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule, 1}];

lengthoflistofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegrbeforemultiplyingwiththefirstfa
 ctors = Length[
  listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegrbeforemultiplyingwiththefirstfactors];

table4 = PadLeft[listofthefirstfactorsofSimpsrule, 
 lengthoflistofthefirsttermsofthesecondfactorofSimpsrule, 
  listofthefirstfactorsofSimpsrule];

lengthoftable4 = Length[table4];

listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr = 
 Thread[Times[table4, 
  listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegrbeforemultiplyingwiththefirstfactors]];

lengthoflistofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr =   
 Length[listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr];

listofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩaccompaniedbythevlsofαβΩ = 
 Flatten[Table[
  With[{α = α, β = β, 
   Ω = Ω}, (α*Cos[Ω*(#2 + t0)]*#1 - β*#1^2) {α, β, Ω} &], {α, 
    initvlofα, finvlofα, incrstepofα}, {β, initvlofβ, finvlofβ, 
     incrstepofβ}, {Ω, initvlofΩ, finvlofΩ, incrstepofΩ}]];

listofthevlsofαβΩ = 
 Table[listofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩaccompaniedbythevlsofαβΩ[[index9, 1,
  2]], {index9, 1, lengthoflistofzfordifferentvlsofαβΩ, 1}];

table5 = Flatten[
 Transpose[Table[listofthevlsofαβΩ, {index10, lengthofs}]], 1];

listofthevlsofγ = Table[{γ}, {γ, initvlofγ, finvlofγ, incrstepofγ}];

table6 = Flatten[Table[listofthevlsofγ, {index12, 
 numberofvlsofα*numberofvlsofβ*numberofvlsofΩ}], 1];

listofthevlsofαβΩγ = 
 Table[table5[[index13]]~Join~table6[[index13]], {index13, 1, 
  lengthoflistofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr, 1}];

table7 = Range[1, lengthoflistofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr, 1];

listofthevlsofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfun = 
 listofthevlsofαβΩγ[[#]]~Join~{{#}} & /@ table7;

list1 = {};list2 = {};

table8 = For[index15 = 1, 
 index15 <= lengthoflistofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr, 
  index15 = index15 + 1, 
   If[Resolve[
    Exists[t0, listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr[[index15]] == 0 ], 
     Reals], AppendTo[list1, 
      listofthevlsofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfun[[
       index15]]], 
        AppendTo[list2, 
       listofthevlsofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfun[[
         index15]]]]];

listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhichMelnfu
 nhavezeros = list1;

lengthoflistofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhi
 chMelnfunhavezeros = 
  Length[listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhi
   chMelnfunhavezeros];

listofindexesofMelnfunthathavezeros = 
 Table[listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhic
  hMelnfunhavezeros[[index17, 5, 1]], {index17, 1, 
   lengthoflistofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunfor
    whichMelnfunhavezeros, 1}];

lengthoflistofindexesofMelnfunthathavezeros = 
 Length[listofindexesofMelnfunthathavezeros];

listofMelnfunwhichhavezeros = 
 Table[listofMelnfunthroughSimpsintegr[[index18]], {index18, 
  listofindexesofMelnfunthathavezeros}];

lengthoflistofMelnfunwhichhavezeros =   
 Length[listofMelnfunwhichhavezeros];

listofthederivativesofMelnfunthathavezeros =   
 D[listofMelnfunwhichhavezeros, t0];

list3 = {};list4 = {};

table9 = For[index25 = 1, 
 index25 <= lengthoflistofMelnfunwhichhavezeros, 
  index25 = index25 + 1, 
   If[Resolve[
    Exists[t0, 
     Abs[listofMelnfunwhichhavezeros[[index25]]] + 
      Abs[listofthederivativesofMelnfunthathavezeros[[index25]]] == 
       0], Reals], 
        AppendTo[list3, 
      listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhichMe
       lnfunhavezeros[[index25]]], 
        AppendTo[list4, 
       listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhichMe
        lnfunhavezeros[[index25]]]]];

listofαβΩγaccompaniedbytheindexofthecorrespondingMelnfunforwhichMelnfu
 nhaveonlysimplezeros = list4;
```

Comment: The most compact way to solve this would be `{list1,list2} = 
  GatherBy[listoffuns, Resolve[Exists[t, # == 0], Reals] &];` but the `Resolve[...]` is still the slowest part taking an avg of 0.01742 seconds per function tested on my machine

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[listoffuns, Resolve[Exists[t, # == 0], Reals] &]
```

Constructs `list1` for you and

```
Select[listoffuns, !Resolve[Exists[t, # == 0], Reals] &]
```

constructs `lists2`. However the test `Resolve[Exists[t, # == 0], Reals] &` is computationally so expensive, that the `For` loop does not add any significant overhead. You'd be best off performing a refined test based on coefficients. In this case `(Abs[b] > Abs[a]) &`

As Histograms suggests in the comments,

```
{list2, list1} = GatherBy[listoffuns, Resolve[Exists[t, # == 0], Reals] &]
```

Note, that I write `{list2, list1}` and not the other way round, as `GatherBy` returns first the list which returns `False` on the test, and then the one with `True`.

Comment: Using `GatherBy` as in my comment on the question would be more efficient than performing two separate selects.

Comment: Exactly two times as efficient, in fact. I'll add that. I was thinking, along the lines that one list is the complement of the other...

Comment: Yeah, that would work too with `Complement`. Still cant figure out a faster way around Resolve for the general case though :(  A refined test, like you say, looks to be the best approach. It looks like the functions provided have zeros whenever `(-c d \[PlusMinus] ArcCos[-(a/b)] + 2 \[Pi])/c` exists